# Parsing @XmlAnyElement(lax = true) from soap response

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, wsimport

I am trying to consume healthcare related webservice to validate DEA number. I have created client class using WSDL tool. I am providing the SOAP response and the client class generated by WSDL to handle SOAP response. Please provide solution to parse response XML . Especially @XmlAnyElement(lax = true) element.

Here is my response xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="DEA">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Dea" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="BAC" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Drug_x0020_Schedule" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Expiration_x0020_Date" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Company_x0020_Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Address_1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Address_2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Address_3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Address_4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Zip_x0020_Code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Drug_x0020_Codes" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="BASC" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Payment_x0020_Indicator" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Activity" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="siganture_date" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="URL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
      <DEA diffgr:id="DEA1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <Dea>*******</Dea>
        <BAC>C</BAC>
        <Drug_x0020_Schedule>*******</Drug_x0020_Schedule>
        <Expiration_x0020_Date>*******</Expiration_x0020_Date>
        <Company_x0020_Name>*******</Company_x0020_Name>
        <Address_1 xml:space="preserve"></Address_1>
        <Address_2>*******</Address_2>
        <Address_3 xml:space="preserve"></Address_3>
        <Address_4>*******</Address_4>
        <State>**</State>
        <Zip_x0020_Code>****</Zip_x0020_Code>
        <BASC>*</BASC>
        <Payment_x0020_Indicator>*</Payment_x0020_Indicator>
        <Activity>****</Activity>
        <siganture_date>*****</siganture_date>
        <URL/>
      </DEA>
    </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Here is my client class to handle response

```
package org.tempuri;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import org.w3._2001.xmlschema.Schema;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="GetQueryResult" minOccurs="0">
 *           &lt;complexType>
 *             &lt;complexContent>
 *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                 &lt;sequence>
 *                   &lt;element ref="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}schema"/>
 *                   &lt;any/>
 *                 &lt;/sequence>
 *               &lt;/restriction>
 *             &lt;/complexContent>
 *           &lt;/complexType>
 *         &lt;/element>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "getQueryResult"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetQueryResponse")
public class GetQueryResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "GetQueryResult")
    protected GetQueryResponse.GetQueryResult getQueryResult;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the getQueryResult property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link GetQueryResponse.GetQueryResult }
     *     
     */
    public GetQueryResponse.GetQueryResult getGetQueryResult() {
        return getQueryResult;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the getQueryResult property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link GetQueryResponse.GetQueryResult }
     *     
     */
    public void setGetQueryResult(GetQueryResponse.GetQueryResult value) {
        this.getQueryResult = value;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;element ref="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}schema"/>
     *         &lt;any/>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "schema",
        "any"
    })
    public static class GetQueryResult {

        @XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", required = true)
        protected Schema schema;
        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        protected Object any;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the schema property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link Schema }
         *     
         */
        public Schema getSchema() {
            return schema;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the schema property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link Schema }
         *     
         */
        public void setSchema(Schema value) {
            this.schema = value;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the value of the any property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link Object }
         *     
         */
        public Object getAny() {
            return any;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the any property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link Object }
         *     
         */
        public void setAny(Object value) {
            this.any = value;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You can try looking into the Axis2 framework.

Comment: is it not possible with client classes generated by WSIMPORT tool ?